# swiper矢印をhoverしたら現れるようにしたい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, swiper

画像スクローラにswiperを使っています。gemでswiper-railsというのがありそれでrailsに導入しました。
動作するようになったのですが、デフォルトだと[image: イメージ]画像にhoverしたら矢印が現れるようにできません。デフォルトでは消しといてhoverしたら矢印が現れるようにできる方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

```
.swiper-container
  .swiper-wrapper
    .swiper-slide
      = image_tag hoge.image1.url
    .swiper-slide
      = image_tag hoge.image2.url
    .swiper-slide
      = image_tag hoge.image3.url
  .swiper-pagination
  .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black
  .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black
```

javascript

```
mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',
  direction: 'horizontal'
  loop: true
  autoplay: 5000
  autoResize: true
  calculateHeight: true
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination'
  paginationClickable: true
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next'
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
.container-fluid .swiper-container:hover .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black {
  visibility: visible;
}
.container-fluid .swiper-container:hover .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black {
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```